# Qt QCryptographicHash Problems

Tags: c++, qt

I'm attempting to distribute a program which includes the use of QCryptographicHash for some simple authentication. The code is like this:

```
QString myDigest = mySalt + userName.toUpper();
QString myHash = QCryptographicHash::hash( myDigest.toAscii(), QCryptographicHash::Sha1 ).toHex();
```

The user is given this hash, which acts as a serial key. To use the program, they must enter their username and serial.

The problem is, this works on some computers, but not others. Does anyone know what could be causing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe toUpper has different behavior depending on the locale?  Does qt have a toUpperInvariant like C#?

Comment: I tried using QLocale::toUpper() with the US English locale, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Then you need to print out detailed debugging information on each computer so you can see which step of the computation differs.